# iPhone - can I use MapKit without displaying a Map?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit

I am writing an app that will use Reverse Geocoding to translate the user's current location into something like a Street Address or City. It seems the only way to get this kind of information is via MapKit (specifically the Placemark class).

Can I use this without having to display a map to the user?

The reason I am asking this is because in the [Google HTTP Reverse Geocoding documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html) it states:

> Note: the geocoding service may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions.

I'm wondering if this holds true for the MapKit API as well or if Google and Apple worked something out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question way too much around here -

> 10.12 use or display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps API Documentation, the Street View API Documentation, or through written permission from Google (for example, you must not use geocodes obtained through the Service except in conjunction with a Google map, but the Street View API Documentation explicitly permits you to display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map); or

via [Google Maps iPhone TOS](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html)

Comment: You can use an existing free service to reverse geocode.  I saw this a while back http://www.viawindowslive.com/Articles/VirtualEarth/Freereversegeocoding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Map Kit framework provides an embeddable map interface for your application. Use it to display map or satellite imagery from the windows and views of your custom applications. You can also use the framework to annotate your maps with points of interest and other custom information.

What was stated above about using Googles HTTP API for reverse geocoding would be a better way to display the information you are looking for and using a text box to read the information.